# How can I execute the results of compile_file?

Tags: maxima

compile_file() creates some output files. None of these can be used with load() or loadfile() or batch() or can from the shell commandline. And there is no example how one can use them.

Comment: `compile_file` is supposed to generate a Lisp file which you can load. If it doesn't, that's a bug. Can you describe what error you are running into? Also what is the output of `build_info();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an example from the test suite.](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/tests/rtest_translator.mac)

```
(kill (all),
 lisp_name : ssubst ("_", " ", build_info()@lisp_name),
 maxima_filename : sconcat (maxima_tempdir, "/tmp-rtest_translator-compile_file-", lisp_name, ".mac"),
 fasl_filename : sconcat (maxima_tempdir, "/tmp-rtest_translator-compile_file-", lisp_name, ".fasl"),
 lisp_filename : sconcat (maxima_tempdir, "/tmp-rtest_translator-compile_file-", lisp_name, ".LISP"),
 maxima_output : openw (maxima_filename),
 maxima_content :
"foo (x) := my_foo * x;
Foo (x) := my_Foo * x;
FOO (x) := my_FOO * x;
[my_foo, my_Foo, my_FOO] : [123, 456, 789];
results : [foo (2), Foo (3), FOO (4)];
my_test () := is (results = [2*123, 3*456, 4*789]);",
 printf (maxima_output, maxima_content),
 close (maxima_output),
 compile_file (maxima_filename, fasl_filename, lisp_filename),
 kill (allbut (lisp_filename)),
 load (lisp_filename),
 my_test ());
```